# Remove items from tuple if substring exists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a tuple that looks like this

```
full = [('Ethernet4/3', 'odsa', 'connected'),('Port-Channel161', 'odsa', 'connected'),('Port-Channel545', 'odsa', 'connected')]
```

I want to remove all the Port-Channels to return only the interfaces. I can hard code each Port-Channel in a list and remove it that way, but that isn't very scalable. I'm trying to remove anything with 'Port' in it from a list, so my script looks like this

```
full = [('Ethernet4/3', 'odsa', 'connected'),('Port-Channel161', 'odsa', 'connected')]

skip_interfaces = ['Ethernet49/1', 'Ethernet49/2', 'Ethernet49/3', 'Ethernet49/4', 'Ethernet50/1', 'Ethernet50/2', 'Ethernet50/3','Ethernet50/4','Ethernet51/1',
                    'Ethernet51/2', 'Ethernet51/3', 'Ethernet51/4', 'Ethernet52/1', 'Ethernet52/2', 'Ethernet52/3', 'Ethernet52/4', 'Port', 'Management1', 'Port-Channel44', 'Port-Channel34']


new = [tup for tup in full if tup[0] not in skip_interfaces]

print new
```

But when printed i still get

```
[('Ethernet4/3', 'odsa', 'connected'),('Port-Channel161', 'odsa', 'connected'),('Port-Channel545', 'odsa', 'connected')]
```

Is there a better way to remove items from a tuple when a substring is in a list?

Thanks

Comment: What would you expect to happen? None of the first elements in `full` are in `skip_interfaces`...

Comment: You cannot remove elements from a tuple, since they are immutable. So, please, be consistent in using the terms `list` and `tuple`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `str.startswith` to filter out all tuples whose first element begins with "Port", or "Port-Channel", using a list comprehension. `str.startwsith` can be used in conjunction with a couple of alternatives, listed below.

**Option 1**
*list comprehension*

```
>>> [i for i in full if not i[0].startswith('Port')]  # .startswith('Port-Channel')
[('Ethernet4/3', 'odsa', 'connected')]
```

Alternatively, you can perform a `not in` check on `i[0]`, which will filter elements based on whether `i[0]` contains "Port" anywhere.

```
>>> [i for i in full if 'Port' not in i[0]]
[('Ethernet4/3', 'odsa', 'connected')]
```

---

**Option 2**
*vanilla `for` loop*
A second approach (very similar to the first) is using a plain ol' `for` loop. Iterate over `full` and make a check with an `if` clause.

```
r = []
for i in full:
    if not i[0].startswith('Port'):
         r.append(i)
```

---

**Option 3**
*`filter`*
`filter` is another alternative here. The `filter` removes elements which do not conform to a particular condition. The condition here is the first argument, passed as a `lambda`. The second argument is the list to be filtered.

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: not x[0].startswith('Port'), full))
[('Ethernet4/3', 'odsa', 'connected')]
```

`filter` is generally slower, compared to a list comprehension. Still a useful construct for concise code, and chaining more expressions in a larger pipeline.

---

Note: You should *never* iterate over a list with a loop and remove elements *in place*, using methods such as `remove` and `del`. This would result in your list shrinking, and the end result is that the loop will not have the chance to completely iterate over the list elements.